# c++ loading image from resources visual studios 2012 draw on window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, bitmap, resources, window

Im having problem loading an image in visual studios 2012:

```
case WM_PAINT: 
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(::hInstance, L"apple.jpg", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE); // problem??
            PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
            HDC             hdc;
            BITMAP          bitmap;
            HDC             hdcMem;
            HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;

            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

            GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
return 0;
```

I dragged and dropped the image from my desktop into visual studios 2012 but the image is not appearing in my window.

[image]

I think the problem is the L"apple.jpg", does anyone no what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the "LoadImage" method does not support JPG images. It only supports BMP.

Comment: So what did you do? Did you just change the file extension of the jpegs?